# Expression or function as an argument of Range function

Tags: python

I was wondering, if I use some *expression or function inside **range()***, will it calculate that expression every iteration or just the first time?
For instance, this:

```
l = len(some_array)
for i in range(l):
    ...
```

or

```
for i in range(len(some_array)):
    ...
```

is faster?
Also, is it the same for **enumerate()**?

Comment: No, the function will be evaluated only once. Always use enemerate

Comment: The second way is very slightly faster (since it doesn't need to store and load a variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `range(len(some_array))` instanciates a `range` generator object, then it yields its values, the `len` is computed once and passed to the `range`

To iterate over a structure and have also the position, use `enumarate`, you have already the index and value available, and don't have to compute the length

```
for i, value in enumerate(some_array):
    pass
```